# Powershell - variable scope in function and loop

Tags: powershell, loops, scope

Consider the following:

```
function GetOneOf($prompt, $values) {
    $response=
    while ($response -eq $null) {
        $response = read-host $prompt
        if ( -not ($values -icontains $response)) {
            $response = $null
        }
    }
    $response
}

function GetOneOfV2($prompt, $values) {
    # "$response=" fragment is missing
    while ($response -eq $null) {
        $response = read-host $prompt
        if ( -not ($values -icontains $response)) {
            $response = $null
        }
    }
    $response
}

$resp = GetOneOf 'enter A or B' 'a', 'b'
write-host "RESP: $resp"
$resp = GetOneOfV2 'enter A or B' 'a', 'b'
write-host "RESP: $resp"
```

Why `GetOneOf` does not return entered value and `GetOneOfV2` returns it? I don't see any reason for this to work this way. If the first case (`GetOneOf`) works this way because `while` constitutes another scope and variable can't be changed there then OK, but if so then in second case there should be no way to read value of `$response` in scope outside loop because there was no such variable earlier. In fact I should get `no such variable` or similar error. But if we assume that changes inside loop are visible on the outside (second case) and they even make variable available to outer scope, then how is it possible that first case does not work?

And also how can I make first case (`GetOneOf`) work?

I use the following:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1237
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1237
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nothing related to variable scopes, you are assigning the return value of `while` to `$response`, which is always `null` because you return nothing.

Here this should work:

```
function GetOneOf($prompt, $values) {
    $response=
    while ($response -eq $null) {
        $response = read-host $prompt
        if ( -not ($values -icontains $response)) {
            $response = $null
        } else {
            echo $response
        }
    }
    $response
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> $resp = GetOneOf 'enter A or B' 'a', 'b'
enter A or B: d
enter A or B: f
enter A or B: g
enter A or B: w
enter A or B: a
PS C:\> $resp
a
PS C:\> $resp.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: Wait. You mean that properly what I wrote should be written `$response = while (....`? So sometimes new line separates expressions and sometimes it does not? What a horrible language. Thank you for an answer.

Comment: No it is not, `echo` is the key. It returns value to your variable, it is nothing to do with newline. Check this out: `$x = 1; $a = while ($x -lt 5) {echo $x; $x = $x + 1}` , `$a.GetType() # ---> System.Array`, `$a` is an array of `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: Echo is not the key. If you remove `echo` from your example, everything works as before. On the other hand check out this example: `$x = 1; $a = while ($x -lt 5){ $x ; $x = $x + 1; } ; $a.GetType(); $a`. This basically means that values returned from `while` are assigned to variable `$a`. So what was happening in my case was that `$response` was assigned values returned from `while`, contrary to what one would expected - and I expect that new line terminates statement except when explicitly instructed not to by writing back-tick at the end of the line.

Comment: Ah understand your point, that's correct.